# Is it possible to bulk move issues or tasks via the workfront API?

Tags: attask, workfront-api

I perform bulk updates all the time, but I don't see a way to bulk move objects. How would I go about executing a bulk move?

Answer (score 1):

No need to mess with an API call for this. You can indeed bulk move issues as long as you have appropriate rights.

From your list of issues, check those you want to move, then you should see the "MORE" button appear.  Underneath MORE are the MOVE and COPY commands.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to want to use the API for this. Obviously you can move items in the UI. What if you want to generate an automated archiving system for example. Currently you have to loop over every item moving one at a time.

Comment: Sounds like this is on the workfront roadmap from leap 2017, but no ETA for batch requests.